# A historical cipher

Tags: cipher, history

You are born in the time of 100 BC. Now what?

> gvcwndxphufrcshvrtfrnhwnircssynbntnwnnglcufnbgwrf

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Now this:

> [image: The Great wave]

Eh?

> The given sentence, when decoded, says: "Show a picture of the Great Wave off Kanagawa as your answer", so that's what I did.
>
>  Fellow solver z100 has already employed the help of quipqiup to find most of the answer. Apparently, the text is encoded with a monoalphabetic cipher.
>
>  The cipher is a Caesar shift, but applied to the Latin alphabet as it might have been in 100 BC: The letters J, U and W are missing and are encoded by themselves. With a shift of eleven, we get this encryption table:
>
>  `A B C D E F G H I K L M N O P Q R S T V X Y Z   J U W`   plain
>  `n o p q r s t v x y z a b c d e f g h i k l m   j u w`   code

But, but, ...

> ... how would someone born in 100 BC and living in a region where the Latin alphabet is used know of an iconic [piece of Japanese art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Great_Wave_off_Kanagawa) that was created roughly 19 centuries later? And why would that person give me orders in modern English? (And, most mystifying, why am I obeying their orders?)

Comment: More about Caesar shift here (selection of Use the latin alphabet in the time of Caesar (23 letters, no J, U or W) possible) : https://www.dcode.fr/caesar-cipher

Answer (score 0):

> Show a picture of the great wave off Kanagawa as your answer.

Solved by quipquip.

Comment: You got it right (well actually almost you got one word wrong), but how did Quipquip solve it??

Comment: Monoalphabetic substitution. Corrected now "ambiture" to "a picture".